# restart apache gracefully, but I got some error logs, can I ignore them?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, python-2.6

### Now my tool set is:

1. Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
2. mod_wsgi/3.1
3. Python 2.7.3 (default, May 21 2013, 09:23:44)

### Before, my python version is 2.6,

other apache and mod_wsgi, their version won't be changed.
like the below:
1. Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
2. mod_wsgi/3.1
3. Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jan 28 2010, 08:50:34)

I have not seen the error like the below.
when I gracefully restart apache, apache will output the error:

```
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:43 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:44 2013] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(47472837226624,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.pyo'> ignored

[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.1 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 711)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 712)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 713)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 714)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 715)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 716)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 717)
[Mon Sep 09 08:58:47 2013] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 719)
```

as I know, restart Apache gracefully will not terminate the user request directly, it will be killed after finished the response. but now I think it maybe stop the python sub-thread when I gracefully restart the Apache through the error log

**Can I ignore the error log when I restart Apache gracefully? if not, how can I fix this issue?**

Comment: I think it can help me[https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=modwsgi/uoKyZDVk0t0/jd-3kbJehs0J], the answer from the mod_wsgi author: *Graham Dumpleton*

Comment: the above link is wrong, [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/uoKyZDVk0t0]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=197) bug would tell you that the specific error messages you've mentioned are *harmless* and can be ignored.

(As indicated in the same bug report, the issue has been fixed in mod_wsgi 3.3 so you shouldn't see the error after upgrading!)

Comment: yes, I have also checked that report.maybe I should contact our infrastructure engineer to update that.